# ArcPy UpdateCursor - Attribute column not found

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, cursor, geocoding

I have a rather lengthy script that I'm testing by pasting the code into the ArcGIS Pro Python command window. The script takes a table for geocoding, attempts to fix errors such misspelled cities to associate them with their respective zipcodes in a rematch series and also cleans up artifacts in address field such as '#' symbols and "AP" for apartment.

Everything runs fine until I get to this part of the script that runs as part of a larger loop:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(outFC, ['inZip'], WC) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = i
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 92, in <module>
RuntimeError: Attribute column not found [MyDB.AC.ssaGeocode_phase1][STATE_ID = 2]
```

*NOTE:

Here is the entire script for context:

```
# This script is intended to apply some of the troubleshooting techniques to geocode addresses
# with data entry errors in the zip code. Should only be ran after city names have been corrected.

# import arcpy library
import arcpy
import difflib

# make default geodatabse
repDB = r"\\MyDB.AC.sde"
arcpy.env.workspace = repDB

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# input table with addresses

adTable = r"\\MyDB.AC.sde\inputGeocodeaddreesesSSA_3"

# reference table with cities and associated zips
cityZips = r"C:\Data\Alco_City_Zips.csv"

# Create a set for unique correct input address city names using cityZips (p stands for place)
pSet = set()

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(cityZips, "City") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        pSet.add(row[0])

# convert set with unique values to list so it can be used in cursor

pList = []

for i in pSet:
    pList.append(i)

# add field for correct city name spelling

# arcpy.management.AddField('Replication_DB.AC.inputGeoCode_ssa',"CorPlace", 'TEXT')

# p = "Hollingwood" test criteria should be "Rollingwood"

# x = difflib.get_close_matches(p, pList, n=1, cutoff=.5)
# print x -- This returned "Rollingwood"

# replace mispelled inCity field values with correctly spelled city names 
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(adTable, ["inCity", "inStreet"]) as cursor:
    #if first time, put in print prompt
    for row in cursor:
        x = difflib.get_close_matches(row[0].title(), pList, n=1, cutoff=.75)
        print (x, row[0])
        if len(x) > 0:
            row[0] = x[0]
        if "#" in row[1]:
            row[1] = row[1].split("#")[0]
        if " AP " in row[1]:
            row[1] = row[1].split(" AP ")[0]
    
        cursor.updateRow(row)

# input locator
loc = r"C:\\ArcGIS\Locators\Address_Points_Locator.loc"

outFC = r"\\MyDB.AC.sde\ssaGeocode_phase1"

arcpy.geocoding.GeocodeAddresses(adTable, loc, "'Street or Intersection' inStreet VISIBLE NONE;'City or Placename' inCity VISIBLE NONE;'ZIP Code' inZip VISIBLE NONE", outFC, "STATIC", None, '', None, '')

# Create values for query to be used in the rematch process (Q = query, F = field, V = value)
QF1 = "Status"
QF2 = "inCity"
QV1 = "U"

# loop through each place name to fix zip codes so that an address match can be made
try: 
    for x in pList:
        QV2 = x
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(cityZips,['City','ZIP']) as rows:
            # Build a list of unique zip codes for the current place
            zipSet = set()
            zipList = []
            for row in rows:
                if row[0] == x:
                    zipSet.add(row[1])
            for i in zipSet:
                zipList.append(i)
                print(i)
            print (zipList)
            if len(zipList) > 0:
                for i in zipList: # For the current place loop through each of it's zip codes, and apply the rematch after changing the zip code
                    print (i)
                    WC = """{0} = '{1}' AND {2} = '{3}' """.format(QF1,QV1, QF2, QV2)
                    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(outFC, ['inZip'], WC) as cursor:
                        for row in cursor:
                            row[0] = i
                            cursor.updateRow(row)
                    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(outFC, "NEW_SELECTION", WC)
                    selCount = arcpy.GetCount_management(outFC)
                    # print only for testing - should remove once in production
                    print (selCount)
                    if selCount > 0:
                        arcpy.geocoding.RematchAddresses(outFC, WC)
                    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(outFC, "NEW_SELECTION",""""Status" = 'U'""")
                    unGeoCount = arcpy.GetCount_management(outFC)
                    # only use this print statement during testing
                    print ("Unmatched addresses = " + str(unGeoCount))
                    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(outFC, "CLEAR_SELECTION")

except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    print(arcpy.GetMessages(2))
```

Comment: The code logic looks *off*. Nesting cursors is rarely a good idea, and your UpdateCursor  is the equivalent of a CalculateField, since there is no change of contents. The error message indicates the column is not present.

Comment: @ Vince I thought nesting cursors were ok as long as they were different types of cursors. This same code worked for me several years ago.

Comment: Cursor in cursor is frowned upon from a performance point-of-view, it's much quicker to ingest all the values into a set, list or dict then access as needed in the 2nd and subsequent cursors. The error message should give you the line number that the code is failing on, go to that line and double check the fields do exist in your data. If you're still stumped can you trim your code down to that line and a few preceding lines, with the content of the error message, I'm too lazy to read all of your code to try to spot the error.

Comment: Thanks for trimming down. I'd say the problem is in WC, considering you're using double quotes on the end they should only need to be single, not triple, **WC = "{0} = '{1}' AND {2} = '{3}' ".format(QF1,QV1, QF2, QV2)** might be the solution. Double check that fields called *Status* and *inCity* exist in your table.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Thanks for the suggestion and looking into it deeper. It was the fields. The field names seem to get altered in the geocoded event from inCity to USER_inCity while converting the initial field name to the new field's alias. I changed the code and it's not failing but you're right about the performance. I need to convert the search cursor step prior to the update cursor into a dict where cities are the keys and their associated zips are the values.